# Hard disk Cylinder explaination

Tags: disk

I am currently learning about how HDD's function and in particular i am having trouble understanding what a **Cylinder** in a HDD is.

I have read online and my current understanding is that it is when a portition of the hard disk track is aligned with another track from another platter which contains similiar data such as a file.

but im not quite sure if that is even correct.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a general hardware question unrelated to Unix & Linux as defined in the [help/on-topic]

Comment: It is related to unix and linux beacuse in the linux parþed command it talks about cylinders and im not sure what they are....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [wikipedia explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder-head-sector), a harddisk consists of several platters. Each platter has concentric tracks with data. The set of all tracks in the same position, for all platters, makes up a cylinder. It's called cylinder because it has the geometrical shape of a cylinder (well, more or less).

There is no relation to "containing similar data". None at all.

At least for early harddisks, the movement of the read-write-heads was coupled, so "cylinder number" was really a description for "how far do the read-write-heads have to move inside on all the platters".

Today, the head/sector/cylinder addressing is obsolete, and everyone uses *logical block addresses* (LBAs). The harddisk firmware is responsible for translating a LBA into head movements etc.

Comment: Ok so your saying that its when all the tracks are alligned in the same position. How does that even work? Arent tracks all the same size?

Comment: No. _Sectors_ are the same size, but since tracks are concentric, inner tracks have fewer sectors each than outer tracks.

Comment: I'm not saying "all tracks are aligned in the same position". I am saying "the collection of all tracks **in** the same position (think: with a certain diameter) form a cylinder". Imagine a half-transparent (geometric) cylinder shape going "through" the stack of platters. Where the cylinder surface intersects with the platters, you have the tracks that make up the "hard-disk cylinder".